# Selenium Webdriver C# storing the id as variable form the page

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, guid

I am using selenium web driver using c# and Nunit framework. I am trying to automate the application form which has been developed in MVC. The issues is ever new database build, I get new GUID for each element. For example in the bellow code, id has a value which changes with each new database build.

```
<select id="e61a05cf-477c-4177-8adc-49686e0902ee__8cdbdcd0-c85a-4654-bab3-92c2c663ba8c-value" class="form-control">
        <option selected="" value=""></option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

I will appreciate if someone can help me to extract this id's in the advance and store it as the variable so that I can use it for passing the value. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Would you not be happier selecting the element with `classname`.

Comment: Hi Marwaha, most of the questions refers to the same class. I did a find a work around by locating the element by XPath e.g. 

new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[6]/div/div[2]/div/select"))).SelectByText("No");

But I am not too sure how much it is reliable if the relative path changes. I will appreciate any help to retrieve the hidden id text from the form.

Comment: Can you post the body html code? I wanna see if we can 'hone' in without using ID but still differentiate between the elements.

Comment: @marwaha.ks please send me your email address so that i can send you the HTML body text.